# Error on executing libreoffice command using shell_exec()

Tags: php, linux, shell, libreoffice

Code:

```
shell_exec('libreoffice --convert-to pdf `'.$my_file.'` --headless');
```

I have tried this too

```
shell_exec('libreoffice --convert-to pdf `'.$my_file'` --headless > /dev/null');
```

Error on the server while executing above:

> Output:sh: /my_files/my_file.doc: cannot execute binary file

**Note:** All other commands of linux working fine with `shell_exec()` just `libreoffice` command not working. And on linux terminal the `libreoffice` command working fine just not working using `PHP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using backticks, which tells the subshell to run that command and use its output in its place. Use double quotes instead, and it will work far more often.

Comment: Now, I dont get any error but files are not being converted 
`shell_exec("libreoffice --convert-to pdf ".$my_file." --headless");`

Comment: You didn't replace just the backticks with double quotes. `shell_exec('libreoffice --convert-to pdf "' . $my_file . '" --headless')` -- but now you have a different problem from before, and maybe should merit a new question.

Comment: I tried doing this too, no luck. not converting the file using php, but able to convert using terminal. I tried all possible quote options.

Comment: Sorry my bad, its actually working but saving the file into web directory, I just added my dir path to save the converted file on the command. THanks